# Matplotlib - Plot result of Python for loop

Tags: python, csv, datetime, matplotlib

I have a .csv file that adds a new line every second.  Each line looks like this:

```
"03/08/2018 16:03:03.767","105.000000"
```

I am trying to plot it by using the following code that I copied and tuned from different posts:

```
import os
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open(r'c:\temp\samples.csv', 'r') as entrada:
    contador = 0
    for linea in entrada:
        quitar_comillas = linea.replace('"','')
        leer_nueva_linea = quitar_comillas[23:27]
        hasta_el_punto = leer_nueva_linea.partition(".")[0]
        contador = contador + 1
        juntador = str(contador) + hasta_el_punto

x = []
y = []

plots = linea.reader(juntador, delimiter=',')
for row in plots:
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])

plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

After running it I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 22, in 
>   IndexError: list index out of range

So I have the following question:

***What would be the proper approach to read lines from CSV and parsing that line into a variable so that it is plotted?***

I'm not sure if the logic is correct ( I have x and y delimited by a comma iterating through each line ).  I would say I'm making a mistake with matplotlib methods but I don't know if it's that or if I'm making this all wrong.

Could you please point me out?

Thanks much!

Comment: Why not review standard llibrary `csv`  module documentation, or pandas `read_csv()` documentation for this? `plots = linea.reader(juntador, delimiter=',')` looks as inidentifiable call. Even better separate your efforts into _Can read this csv file?_ and _Can I plot the data I read_. The two combined together in one question is a bit hard to follow/help.

Comment: Thanks Martin,  I've understood that I need to split questions that might contain more than one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the CSV reader to read each row in and skip any blank lines. Next the values need to be converted. For the date this needs to be converted first into a `datetime` object and then into a matplotlib number. The other value needs to be converted into a float.

Next you need to tell matplotlib to use a date formatter for plotting on the x axis. You can choose the format, here I have just used day month year:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DateFormatter
from datetime import datetime


with open(r'c:\temp\samples.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_input:
    x, y = [], []

    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        if row:
            x.append(date2num(datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')))
            y.append(float(row[1]))

hfmt = DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)            

plt.plot(x, y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Tested on Python 3.x. If you are using Python 2.x, you will need to change:

```
with open(r'c:\temp\samples.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing it, Martin.

I think that my logic was incorrect then.

I'd used "plots = csv.reader(juntador, delimiter=',')"

being almost sure that "juntador" was going to hold the values "1,109" for example.

However you used:

    for row in csv.reader(f_input):

pointing to the file opened.

Last but not least I would never have thought in using dates functions from matplotlib.

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! The csv reader gives you a row at a time in a list format.